# Laptop wont Switch on.. Power button LED Blinks when I press power button

Tags: boot, laptop, power-supply, hardware-failure

My Laptop is **Lenovo T430**. Tried following steps with No luck.

Refer to my Video [here](https://youtu.be/fQnwoI1Q_qg).

- Try charging the Battery to Full
- Remove Battery and tried booting it with Power directly.
- Changed the Keyboard.
- Removed the Bios Battery and tried to switch on.
- Removed the RAM and tried to switch On.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried pressing and holding the power button?

2. Does the CPU fan turn on at all?

3. Any ideas what caused this problem?

I had a similar problem on a Toshiba laptop after water damage. I had to totally disassemble it and clean up the corrosion everywhere. I had to replace the keyboard and power button which was on a separate PCB board with media buttons.

Comment: Yeah I did. CPU fan wont turn. Still a mystery,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is with the motherboard.
First, you need to check if the required +19V voltage is supplied to the MB power jack. So, you need to use multimeter to measure DC voltage between the + contact and the ground.
If it is fine and doesn't drop below when you press power button, then to need to check the other power circuits supplied from the main power source.
+19V is converted into several stand-by voltages required (+3.3, +5) to the other lower VSB voltages (+1.25, +2.5) supplied to SIO/MIO, south bridge, keyboard controller and battery charger.
If you are not familiar with digital design and electronics, you'd better pass it to the service center.

From you can you - make sure that there are no remaining of the liquids, decayed elements. May be you'll find some spots of another color on the places of the lost elements (resistors, capacitors, transistors). Clean the board with Flux-off, isopropyl alcohol or similar.